# Camera Error 100, Media Server and Camera Server

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have been playing around with mediarecorders since yesterday and I can't get around a camera error 100. I keep getting

```
08-13 11:23:24.952: I/System.out(2418): Going to get the camera
08-13 11:23:25.092: I/System.out(2418): This is the camera android.hardware.Camera@4051b208
08-13 11:23:25.273: I/System.out(2418): Surface was created
08-13 11:23:25.282: I/System.out(2418): Stop preview worked android.hardware.Camera@4051b208
08-13 11:23:25.282: I/System.out(2418): Surface changed
08-13 11:23:31.302: I/System.out(2418): This is the camera android.hardware.Camera@40520d20
08-13 11:23:31.345: I/System.out(2418): Trying to save picture
08-13 11:23:31.352: I/System.out(2418): About to preview
08-13 11:23:31.352: I/System.out(2418): Preview worked
08-13 11:23:31.352: I/MediaRecorderJNI(2418): prepare: surface=0x2a8198 (identity=216)
08-13 11:23:31.362: I/System.out(2418): Starting to record
08-13 11:23:32.512: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(2418): media server died
08-13 11:23:32.512: W/Camera(2418): Camera server died!
08-13 11:23:32.512: W/Camera(2418): ICamera died
08-13 11:23:32.522: I/System.out(2418): Stop preview worked android.hardware.Camera@40520d20
08-13 11:23:32.522: I/System.out(2418): Surface changed
08-13 11:23:32.592: E/Camera(2418): Error 100
```

I don't understand how. I released the camera before creating the mediarecorder and unlocking it. Just can't wrap my head around it. This is what I did.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private Camera mCamera;
     private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
     private CameraPreview mPreview;
     private static final String TAG = "Message";
     public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
     public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
     private boolean isRecording = false;
     Button captureButton;
     FrameLayout preview;
     FrameLayout myCameraPreview;
     private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
     private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.preview);
            System.out.println("Going to get the camera");


            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            //mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
          /*  mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

            preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

            preview.addView(mPreview);*/
          //  setPreviewCallback(null);

            myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, mCamera);
            myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

           captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
            captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                         if (isRecording) {
                                // stop recording and release camera
                                mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                                mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                                // inform the user that recording has stopped
                                captureButton.setText("Capture");
                                isRecording = false;
                            } else {
                                // initialize video camera


                                if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                                    System.out.println("Starting to record");
                                    // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                                    // now you can start recording
                                    //releaseCamera();
                                    mMediaRecorder.start(); 

                                    // inform the user that recording has started
                                    captureButton.setText("Stop");
                                    isRecording = true;
                                } else {
                                    // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                                    System.out.println("Recording failed");
                                    releaseMediaRecorder();
                                    // inform user
                                }
                            }
                        }

                }
            );
    }
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
            System.out.println("This is the camera "+c);// attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            System.out.println("Didn't get the camera ");
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
        releaseCamera();
        //preview.removeAllViews();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myCameraSurfaceView.mCamera=mCamera;
        //myCameraView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, mCamera);
        //myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        //myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraView);

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        //mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        System.out.println("About to preview");
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        System.out.println("Preview worked");
        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }




    @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
       releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
   }

   private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
       if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
           mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
           mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
           mMediaRecorder = null;
           mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
       }
   }

   private void releaseCamera(){
       if (mCamera != null){

           mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
           mCamera = null;
       }
   }
    public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
           private Camera mCamera;

        public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
               super(context);
               mCamera = camera;

               // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
               // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
               mHolder = getHolder();
               mHolder.addCallback(this);
               // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
               mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
           }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
          int height) {
               // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
               // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

               if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                 // preview surface does not exist
                 return;
               }

               // stop preview before making changes
               try {
                   mCamera.stopPreview();
                   System.out.println("Stop preview worked "+mCamera);
               } catch (Exception e){
                 // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
                   System.out.println("tried to stop a non-existent preview "+mCamera);
               }

               // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

               // start preview with new settings
               try {

                   mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                   mCamera.startPreview();
                   System.out.println("Surface changed");
               } catch (Exception e){
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
               try {
                   mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                   mCamera.startPreview();
                   System.out.println("Surface was created");
               } catch (IOException e) {
               }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        }
}
```

I'm pretty much confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the error is a result of a know bug with XE19.1.
After I set parameters.setRecordingHint(true)
my video camera started working again.
Hope this also help you